# How do i render my list of complaints into cards to be able to view them?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have built a complaint management system, where the system can accept complaints from the users, view and edit them. The user right now is able to submit the complaints and these get stored in the admin panel.
For the view complaints page, I have these cards through which they can view the complaints. How do I do that so that only a certain number of cards are seen on the screen. For eg: If there are two complaints, then the user sees two cards and so on. Also how di I display the information in these cards? I'm guessing it'll be through a list and a for loop and stuff but I don't know how. What should I write in the views.py and the forms.py?

models.py:

```
class Complaint(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE, null = True, blank=True)
   reportnumber = models.CharField(max_length=500 ,null = True, blank= False)
   eventdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)
   event_type = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   device_problem = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   product_code = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   brand_name = models.CharField(max_length = 300, null=True, blank=True)
   exemption = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   patient_problem = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
   event_text = models.TextField(null=True, blank= True)
   document = models.FileField(upload_to='static/documents', blank=True, null=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.reportnumber
```

forms.py:

```
class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
   input_type = 'date'

class ComplaintForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Complaint
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'reportnumber': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Report number'}),
            'event_type': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Event type'}),
            'eventdate': DateInput(),
            'device_problem': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Device Problem'}),
            'event_text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'style': 'height: 130px;width:760px'}),
            'manufacturer': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Manufacturer Name'}),
            'product_code': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Product Code'}),
            'brand_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Brand Name'}),
            'exemption': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Exemption'}),
            'patient_problem': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Patient 
Problem'}),
        }
    
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ComplaintForm, self).clean()
        reportnumber = cleaned_data.get('reportnumber')
        event_text = cleaned_data.get('event_text')
        if not reportnumber and not event_text:
            raise forms.ValidationError('You have to write something!')
        return cleaned_data
```

template:

```
<div class="col-lg middle middle-complaint-con">
        <i class="fas fa-folder-open fa-4x comp-folder-icon"></i>
        <h1 class="all-comp">My Complaints</h1>
        <p class="all-comp-txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>

        <a href="new.html" style="color:black;">
            <div class="container comp-con-1">
                <p class="history-level-1">Report number</p>
                <p class="comp-title-1">Complaint Title</p>
                <p class="comp-sub-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            </div>
        </a>

        <a href="new.html" style="color:black;">
            <div class="container comp-con-2">
                <p class="history-level-2">Report number</p>
                <p class="comp-title-2">Complaint Title</p>
                <p class="comp-sub-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            </div>
        </a>

        <a href="new.html" style="color:black;">
            <div class="container comp-con-3">
                <p class="history-level-2">Report number</p>
                <p class="comp-title-2">Complaint Title</p>
                <p class="comp-sub-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            </div>
        </a>

        <a href="new.html" style="color:black;">
            <div class="container comp-con-4">
                <p class="history-level-1">Report number</p>
                <p class="comp-title-1">Complaint Title</p>
                <p class="comp-sub-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
```

this is how the page should look:

[image]

The orange and blue cards need to have the complaints info in them. The complaint title is where the event type comes from the complaint model and the report number is the report number and the desc below is the event text.
I don't know how to do this. Can someone please tell me how do i render this and view the complaints in card form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your views.py you will have to fetch the all relevant complaint data from your models, and then pass this fetched data to the template using the context dictionary.

Views.py

```
from .models import Complaint #Importing your model
from django.views import View   #Importing View class
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin #Importing login required check mixin

class MyComplaintHistoryView(LoginRequiredMixin,View):
   def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
      complaint_data = Complaint.objects.filter(user=request.user) # Fetch all the complaint data for this logged in user
      context = { 'complaint':complaint_data }
      return render(request,"yourtempalate.html", context)
```

In your Template.html add this

```
{%for c in complaint %}
        <a href="new.html" style="color:black;">
            <div class="container comp-con-3">
                <p class="history-level-2">{{c.reportnumber}}</p>
                <p class="comp-title-2">{{c.event_title}}</p>
                <p class="comp-sub-2">{{c.event_text}}</p>
            </div>
        </a>
{%endfor%}
```